# Is the matrix a full rank matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x),...\phi_n(x)$ are linear independent,
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
     \phi_1(x_1) & \phi_2(x_1) &  \cdots & \phi_n(x_1) \\
     \phi_1(x_2) & \phi_2(x_2) & \cdots & \phi_n(x_2) \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \vdots \\
     \phi_1(x_m) & \phi_2(x_m) & \cdots & \phi_n(x_m)
     \end{pmatrix}$$

Is $A$ a full rank matrix? ($m>n$),$x_1,x_2,...x_m$ are different.

Comment: Do we at least know that the $x_k$'s are distinct?

Comment: And what are the $\phi_k$? Polynomials?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes,$x_k$ is distinct, $k=1,2,...m$

Comment: I believe that m>n implies this matrix will either have linearly dependent columns or rows and is therefore not full-rank but is rather either full row rank or full column rank.

Comment: @user1537366, $\phi_k$ is not necessarily polynomials.

Comment: I think you can make the matrix the 0-matrix then...

Comment: Now I have a matrix A like this,In the software 'MATLAB',I calculate the rank of A'*A, it says the rank is not equal to n,So I guess the A is not necessarily full rank.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $sin (x) $ and $cos(x)$ are linearly independent. Let's take $n=2$ and $m=3$. Then consider the points (${\pi \over 4}, {\pi\over 4}+2\pi, {\pi\over 4}+4\pi$). Both $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ take the same values at these three points.So, the columns of the matrix are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\phi_k$ are polynomials of degree $<m$.

For all linear combinations $(c_k)$ of the columns:

> Let $q=\sum_k c_k\phi_k$.
>   $$\sum_k c_k\left(\array{\phi_k(x_1)\\\phi_k(x_2)\\\vdots\\\phi_k(x_m)}\right)=0\implies \left(\array{q(x_1)\\q(x_2)\\\vdots\\q(x_m)}\right)=0\implies q=0\implies(c_k)=(0)$$

So the columns are linearly independent.

Otherwise, let $(a_{k,j})_{n\times n}$ be an invertible matrix, and $M$ bigger than all $x_j$.

Let $\phi_k$ be curves (even polynomials of degree $m$) each passing through all the points $(x_j,0)\forall j=1,\ldots,m+1-n$ and also $(M+j,a_{k,j})\forall j=1,\ldots,n$. It is easy to see that they are "linearly independent", but the matrix will have at least $m+1-n$ zero rows, and have a rank of at most $m-(m+1-n)=n-1$, so the columns are linearly dependent.

Comment: But the $\phi_k$ are not necessarily polynomials,for example, $\phi_k=\sqrt{1+(ε_k(x−c_k)^2}$, $c_k$ are distinct.

Comment: @yang Then of course it is not true. See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

While it'd be true for polynomials, for example, a counterexample with $sin$, $\cos$ is given in @Srinivas's answer. Fortunately, your functions are positive definite as I [already](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081440/how-to-prove-the-multiquadric-radius-basis-functions-are-linear-independent/1082146#1082146) pointed out to you. Positive definite functions have their associated interpolation matrices positive definite. Hence the $n\times n$ matrix would be invertible and $m\times n$ of full rank. You can read more about this class of functions in the same textbook I referred you to last time.